# Update 2D List with tuple in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

My List is like this:

```
[('void ', 'treeInit', 'tSymbolTree *T'),('tTreeItemPtr ', 'nodeInsert', 'tTreeItemPtr *T')]
```

and if I call:

```
>>>list[0][0]
void
```

and now it's the problem I using re.sub which returns strign.
and if I call

```
>>>list[0][0] = re.sub('(\s+$),'',newItem)
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Can somebody help me ?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuples` are immutable objects, you cannot assign values to them. You should convert your list of tuples to a list of lists. It would like as follows:

```
[['void ', 'treeInit', 'tSymbolTree *T'], ['tTreeItemPtr ', 'nodeInsert', 'tTreeItemPtr *T]]
```

To convert your list of tuples to a list of strings, you can do:

```
>>> a = [('void ', 'treeInit', 'tSymbolTree *T'),('tTreeItemPtr ', 'nodeInsert', 'tTreeItemPtr *T')]
>>> b = [list(i) for i in a]   #or map(list, a)
>>> print b
[['void ', 'treeInit', 'tSymbolTree *T'], ['tTreeItemPtr ', 'nodeInsert', 'tTreeItemPtr *T]]
```